# oracle maximum cursor problem when query based on gridview data

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have an asp.net grid view that queries the database based on the rows in the grid view. I encountered the below error when the number of rows is more than 30 rows in the grid view.

I do close the connection of SQL after I used it each time. 
Any alternative solution without an increasing number of open cursors.

ora-01000 maximum open cursors exceeded

Comment: I don't know asp.net, but - you're opening cursors and never close them. Increasing number of open cursors won't help much as you'll exceed that value as well, I'm afraid. Re-check your code and - if you have OPEN cursor, don't forget to CLOSE it.

Comment: How are you closing connections?.Share the relevant code opening and closing connections.What web server?